# Pass multiple parameters to controller from a view in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in angular js.

In view i have a list of products, I have to open the detail of the product when i clicked on that. I have to pass 2 parameters to my 'productdetails' controller.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: yes, i can update the question.

Comment: I have updated the tag hence this is `Ionic 1` question.Not an `Ionic 2`.

Answer (score 3):

You miss use angular interpolation (double curly brackets), Also try not to have much functionality in the view code, this should be in the controller / dedicated service.
See code example below

---

View (html)

```
<a ng-click="GetLiveStatus(item)">
```

---

controller (js)

```
function LiveStatusController($location) {
    $scope.GetLiveStatus = function(item){
        // Your code here ...

        // nav part
        $location.path(<'your path string here'>, {<your path params here>});
    }
}
```

Comment: can i redirect to any another view from the controller ?

Comment: Yes you can!
If you're using the regular angular router module ngRoute for defining the app's routes you can simply inject the $location service to your controller and use it in the bounded function.
In a smiliar way you can use the third party module ui-router to do the same only this time use the $state service for it.

See my updated code example.